# Anonymous white space between two divs

Tags: html, css

### Here is the [Fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/y6hSV/1/)

I have two `divs` one is for header and the other is for the main body. Inside the `div` which is for header,  i'm having another `div` and that div was `floated left`. Due to that `floating`, a white space has occurred between those two `divs` (between the div for header and div for main body).

[Note: Please refer `#DivLogo` in the css section of the fiddle]

My question is, why this kind of problem is raising due to floating.?

Comment: make sure your `margin` are all equal to `0`, so are the `padding` of your elements.

Comment: @Ghillied Thanks for your timely reply. By the way I did not set any margin/padding to my inner div

Comment: I added an detailed explanation as to why your problem arose in the first place, please check when you have time. Thank you! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176183/anonymous-white-space-between-two-divs/17176928#17176928

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an artifact of having your #DivHeader be `inline-block`. Change it to `display: block` and set `overflow: hidden;` to contain the floats. See http://jsfiddle.net/jhcUb/

Comment: I just removed the display property from my #DivHeader and I simply added overflow:hidden to it. It [solved](http://jsfiddle.net/jhcUb/1/) the problem. can I use it.? thanks for your timely help.

Comment: Yes - that's essentially the same thing, `<div>` defaults to `display: block;`

Answer (score 4):

#### apply

```
float:left;
```

to `#DivHeader` in order to contain it's descendants

#### remove

```
position:relative;
```

from `#DivMain`

### see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6hSV/17/)

Comment: really thanks for your help. can you tell me what did I do wrong with my css.? why should I have to remove the position relative from my #DivMain.? again thanks for your help

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position under relative value I have to say I am not sure why it behaves this way... What i do know is the #DivHeader couldn't have contained the floated elements under it if it is not floated too

Comment: No problem. I find it good practice to check MDN while encountering these CSS WAT moments. I will also plug w3fools.com in opportunity

Answer (score 3):

### Why The Behavior With inline-block

Your original CSS is as follows:

```css
#DivHeader
{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
    background-color:#3b5998;
}
```

There are two children elements of `#DivHeader`, one is floated and one is absolutely positioned, and as such, do not contribute to the height of `#DivHeader`.

Suppose, that you had set `display: block`, you would have seen the red background painted from the top left corner of the page and you would not see the header.

This is because you set `#DivMain` to `position: relative`, so you created a new stacking context that is painted over the previously rendered elements.

If you had set `position: static` to `#DivMain`, you would see the header content from the floated element.

So, getting back to `#DivHeader`, by using `display: inline-block`, the element now recognizes the white space in your HTML document, creates an anonymous inline box, which means that `#DivHeader` now has content.  Since there is white space after the float, that means the clearance resulting from the float contributes to the inline-block and you see the background color and so on.

Fixing the problem is easy enough, on `DivHeader` set `overflow: auto` and `display: block`.

One more thing, if you had not floated `#DivLogo`, you would not see the problem because the larger font sizes in the logo elements would shift the baseline enough so that the white space being recognized by the inline-block would not matter.

Quite a bit going on here!

Comment: +1 Sir, I have been searching around for this kind of explanations. Thanks for your valuable time that you've spent on my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Your very welcome, this was a fun one, quite a bit going for what appears to be a simple layout.  All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/y6hSV/3/

**HTML**

```html
<div id="DivHeader">

    <div id="DivLogo">

    <span class="Logo" id="SpLogo">Header</span><br/>
    <span class="Logo" id="SpSlogan">{sub header}</span>

    </div>

    <div id="DivPrabhu">
        <a  href="http://google.com">Who?</a>
        <a  href="https://www.facebook.com">Connect</a>
        <a href="#">Feedback/Bugs</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="DivMain">
 Some text to have layout
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
html,body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#DivHeader
{
float: left;
width:100%;
font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
background-color:#3b5998;
}

#DivLogo
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;         /*please remove this property and run*/ 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px
}

.Logo
{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    color:#fff; 
}

#SpLogo
{

    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#SpSlogan
{
    font-size:20px;
}

#DivPrabhu{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}


#DivPrabhu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    margin-left:15px;
}

#DivPrabhu a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

#DivMain{
    height:600px;
    width; 100%;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: i guess he wants to use `float: left;`

Comment: I'm still trying to find what you added. You could write it instead pasting the whole code here and explain what you did to make this work. Did you only write content into the main div?

Comment: Not just content, removed `position` from `#DivMain` added `float: left` to `#DivHeader` and `float: right` to `#DivPrabhu`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `top: -5px;` to `#DivMain` solves your problem!! :)

See the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/y6hSV/24/).

Comment: adding things in it also makes no problem! see http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/y6hSV/25/

Comment: because I did not set any height for that div. It is a kind of flexible one. so we cannot hard code things like -5px. Thanks once again.

Comment: see its working fine with lots of text here: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/y6hSV/26/ I just set the height to 100% you could even set that to `auto`